# scraping webpage data using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have tried to scrape text details of a store location and write them to a csv using BeautifulSoup. 2 stores in Alabama are in class LocationSecContent and 17 stores in Arizona are in another class LocationSecContent.
In Georgia, 1st store Airport is in single class called location inside the class LocationSecContent and the rest 4 in Georgia are in another class location inside LocationSecContent.
I would like to scrape text details and write the store details like name,location,street,phone,fax,hourscontent and all details into a csv file. I'm using firebug in firefox. Sorry, if there are any mistakes, I'm a beginner to beautifulsoup.

here is what i have tried:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get('http://freshvites.com/store-locator/')

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
d={}
for table in soup.find_all("div", {"class":"content freshvites-location"}):
    table
for col in table.find_all("td"):

    LocationSecHdr=col.find_all("div",{'class':'LocationSecHdr'})
    Location=col.find_all("div",{'class':'location'})


dt="LocationSecHdr:%s,Location: %s" %(LocationSecHdr, Location)
zx=BeautifulSoup(dt, "html.parser")

print zx.get_text()
```

I'm not able to iterate through rows and scrape the text.

Method 2:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests


page = requests.get('http://freshvites.com/store-locator/')
#print page


soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
#print soup.find_all('a')

for table in soup.find_all("div",{'class':'content freshvites-location'}):
    table


LocationSecHdr=''
LocationSecContent=''
Location=''
LocationTitle=''
Phone=''
Fax=''
HoursTitle=''
HoursContent=''


for col in table.find_all("td"):      
    LocationSecHdr=col.find_all("div",{'class':'LocationSecHdr'})
    #LocationSecContent= col.find_all("div",{'class':'LocactionSecContent'})
    #Location= col.find_all("div",{'class':'location'})
    LocationTitle= col.find_all("div",{'class':'locationTitle'})
    Phone= col.find_all("div",{'class':'Phone'})
    Fax= col.find_all("div",{'class':'Fax'})
    HoursContent=col.find_all("div",{'class':'HoursContent'})

    data="LocationSecHdr: %s, LocationSecContent: %s, Location:%s, LocationTitle : %s, Phone:%s, Fax :%s, HoursContent:%s " %(LocationSecHdr, LocationSecContent, Location, LocationTitle, Phone, Fax, HoursContent)
    zax=BeautifulSoup(data,"html.parser")

print zax.get_text()
```

If I try this code, i can't get the address of the store and I don't know how to get these details as a dict too

Comment: What's not working with what you've tried?

Comment: loop isnt getting iterated

Comment: Which loop? And how do you know?

Comment: I'm getting key error or list index out of range in this loop LocationSecHdr=col[0].find(text=True)

Comment: I can't find a table that contains locations on the website you are scraping. To me it seems like you are actually looking for `<div class="location">` - If not can you provide some sample data?

Comment: sorry i'm a beginner to beautifulsoup. I'm using firebug in firefox and i could understand that div class=content freshvites-location contains all the details that I want. If I replace content freshvies-location with HoursContent or some other key, I'm getting its values. I just don't know how to iterate the loop and write all the contents to csv.

Comment: @aravind Seems to me that the code you have in your example has wrong indentation (and Python is indentation sensitive) - would you care to edit? Why do you try to find all tr in table and then find all td in table? Shouldn't the second loop be all td in row: `for col in row.find_all("td"):`?

Comment: In the class content fresh-locator, all the details were inside tr and td, so I thought of iterating it, so that I can get the details of all store locators which would be helpful in writing it to csv.
Can you edit and explain the correct codes for iterating and writing it to csv?

Comment: @aravind Aha, you're right, they have table layout like that. On the other hand, there's a captcha on that site, limiting access to non-robots (and requests get HTTP 403 answer) - how do you plan to get the content of the page to start with?

Comment: Im not facing any issues with captcha or limitation in access.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have enough information now to answer your question.

You are looking for the wrong tag/class combination. All informations for a location are contained inside of a `<div class="location">`. Here is a sample:

```
<div class="location">
<div class="locationTitle">32nd Street &amp; Thunderbird</div>
Fresh Vitamins<br> 
13802 N. 32nd St #11<br> 
Phoenix, AZ 85032<br>
<div class="Phone">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="Fax">877.935.6902</div>
<div class="HoursTitle">Hours:</div>
<div class="HoursContent">9am - 7pm M-F<br> 9am - 6pm Sat<br> 11am - 4pm Sun</div>
</div>
```

As you can see in the sample there is no `<tr>` or `<td>` so looking for that doesn't really make sense.

Here's a short python script I put together to find all locations:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get('http://freshvites.com/store-locator/')

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

for div in soup.find_all("div", {"class":"location"}):
    print(div)
```

Now you just need to filter the information you need from `div`. Everything you need for that should be easy to find on so.

Comment: Content freshvites-location gets me the details of everything, including the city like alabama,arizona,washington etc ehich seems to be missing in your class:location. And also, how to iterate and write them as a csv??

Comment: It's not missing - There is `Phoenix, AZ 85032`. AZ=Arizona. What do you want to to iterate? Where are you stuck when writing to a CSV file?

Comment: Iterate div so that i can write all the values to csv